# Open site both on site.name and www.site.name

Tags: nginx

I tried to achieve this as described in [the manual](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) (`server_name .site.name`), but it not seem to work (`404 Not found`). Can I do this without redirecting?

Here is the config.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name .site.name;

    ssl_certificate     certs/mshop-production.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key certs/mshop-production.key;
    passenger_set_cgi_param HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO $scheme;

    error_log /var/log/nginx/mshop-production.error.log error;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/mshop-production.access.log;

    root /home/deployer/apps/production/mshop/current/public;
    passenger_enabled on;
    rails_env production;

    gzip on;
    gzip_types application/x-javascript application/javascript text/javascript text/css;

    client_max_body_size 50m;

    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
            expires 1M;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not modify your A query record in your domain-name server?

I think it is more simple for you .

Answer (score 1):

```
 server_name server.name www.server.name;
```

would do. You can also use wildcards

```
 server_name server.name *.server.name;
```

Comment: `.server.name` should mean both `server.name` and `*.server.name`. However, this one with wildcards doesn't work too. Should I write subdomain stuff someone else in addition to `nginx.conf`?